# Interrupted list formatting options

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, line-spacing

I have an odd list, interrupted by normal text introducing its last item:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-4pt]
\item My first item
\item My second item\\
Along with these should be mentioned:
\item My third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The text between item two and three, "Along with these...", is supposed to break out of the list and start at the left edge of the textblock. How do I push it to the left, if that's at all possible?

I already tried the following between item 2 and 3,

```
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
Along with these should be mentioned:
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-4pt]
\setcounter{enumi}{2}
```

but the inter line space was somewhat off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stop and resume the `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-4pt]
\item My first item
\item My second item
\end{enumerate}      %%<---------------------- stop here
Along with these should be mentioned:
\begin{enumerate}[resume]       %%<----------- resume
\item My third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want tight spacing:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
\item My first item
\item My second item
\end{enumerate}
Along with these should be mentioned:
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item My third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With spaces before and after `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%\begin{enumerate}[nosep,before={\vspace{0.6\baselineskip}},after={\vspace{0.6\baselineskip}}] %% or shorter 
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
\item My first item
\item My second item
\end{enumerate}
Along with these should be mentioned:
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item My third item
\end{enumerate}
Some text again
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your second example looks about good, but the `nosep` option also gets rid of the vertical space before and after the enumeration. I need the tight spacing only between second item and the inserted line, and then again between that line and item 3. But in fact I should consider getting rid of the spaces before or after the list as well.

Comment: @muk.li See the newly added code at the end. It does what you need. :-)

Comment: You probably want `noitemsep` rather than `nosep` and adding vertical space before and below.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I have changed. May be I should get more sleep :-)